# get all columns value from list dynamically? When I get name of column they will be internalName like 'LinkTitle' which is unknown?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

```
function RequestToRetreiveItemFromList(site, listname, paramet, array) {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext(url);
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listname);
    var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
    items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(items);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
        onListDataSucceeded(site, listname, paramet, array);
    }), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListDataFailed));
}

function onListDataSucceeded(site, list, array) {
    var listItemEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
    for (var i in array) {
        if (array[i] == 'LinkTitle') {
            array[i] = 'Title';
        }
        parameter += array[i] + ',';
    }
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        result = [];
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var temp = oListItem.$2_0.$1g_0.$m_dict;
        var property = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(temp);
        var answer;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            for (var j in property) {
                if (property[j] == array[i]) {
                    answer = oListItem.get_item(property[j]);
                    var prop = property[j];
                    result[prop] = [answer];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I use API then I have to write hard code for 'Author' "Author/Title&$expand=Author/Id which I don't want to have hard code. I thought there is another way which I dont know.

Comment: "LinkTitle" is read only field and has same value of "Title" column and which is clickable and used by SharePoint to redirect view that item... so you can filter that column using ReadOnly property of field.. e.g. array[i].ReadyOnly which return true or false..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this would be with two REST calls.

The first would get all columns in the list:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListTitle')/fields
```

Then take all the fields from the result of this call and build the query for your second call dynamically. Check if any of the returned fields are lookups (I think you can just check if the returned value for the field is an object) and for these fields you know you'll need to add `expand`.

Comment: thanks for your solution. I think that I need to filter 'Computed' TypeAsString also.  Right?

Comment: You'll know for sure once you get the result back from the first REST call. Inspect the result and it should become clear how your second REST call should be constructed.

Comment: sure. what I mean is you are not able to get value from fields which has 'computed' as type. I wanted to be sure If I think right.

Comment: You can get back values from Computed columns in your REST call. But you can't filter or sort on Computed columns.

Comment: Can you expand 'App Created By'?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I follow, but can't you use the [SP.ListItem.fieldValues property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj244802.aspx)

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var items = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Tasks").getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
ctx.load(items);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() { 
    items.get_data().forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item.get_fieldValues ())        
    });
}, function(sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
});
```